# toggle-switch-react-native for typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, toggle

I want to use the toggle-switch-react-native component in my Typescript app. I tried installing it like this:

```
yarn add toggle-switch-react-native --save
```

```
@types/toggle-switch-react-native
```

However, I still get an error that:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'toggle-switch-react-native'. '/Users/grannyandsmith/insta/app/node_modules/toggle-switch-react-native/ToggleSwitch.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/toggle-switch-react-native` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'toggle-switch-react-native';`
```

How can I define its types? Is there an alternate? Am I installing it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

This library does not have types, so you need to create a "custom type":

Create a folder called `types/@custom_types`.

Inside that folder, create a file called `declarations.d.ts`.
On the first line of that file, add

```
declare module "toggle-switch-react-native"
```

Answer (score 0):

In npm you should use npm i toggle-switch-react-native --save or npm i toggle-switch-react-native --save-dev. These have been replaced by yarn add and yarn add --dev in yarn. Try this way, might work

Comment: That's not the problem. Problem is with Typescript declarations.